# android - How to compare object variable from getSelectedItem on spinner to Integer value like 1,2 or else?

Tags: android, if-statement, integer, compare, spinner

I have a spinner which is for a clock, so when the user click 10 on spinner, i want to get that number(10) and compare that with integer value like 1, 2, etc.

here is the code :

```
Object index = s1.getSelectedItem();
int a = Integer.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem()); //s1 is a spinner
if(a == 10)
```

i tried this, but its wrong, the "valueOf" only for string, cant compare with integer value, so what should i do if i want to compare that with integer value ? 
if don't mind, please give me an example, thanks.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? How are you setting the items for the Spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int a = Integer.valueOf((String) s1.getSelectedItem());

    if(a == 10)
    {
        //Some code here
    }
```